# Redux inicial state has no effect

Tags: react-redux

I was trying to make a store but for some reason the initial state doesnt change when i alter the inicial state const:
this is the reducer with the inicial state:

```
import { GET_PRODUCT_BY_NAME, ADD_PRODUCT_TO_CART, CLEAR_CART, DELETE_ITEM, CURRENT_PRODUCT,INCREASE_AMOUNT } from '../../actionTypes'

const INITIALSTATE = {
    currentProduct:{},
    product: {},
    list:[]
}

 
export  function ProductReducer(state = INITIALSTATE, action) {
    const { type, payload } = action


    switch (type) {
        case GET_PRODUCT_BY_NAME:
            return {
                ...state,
                user: payload.user,
            }

            case ADD_PRODUCT_TO_CART:
            return {
                ...state,
                list: [...state.list,payload]
            }
            
            case CLEAR_CART:
            return {

                list: []
            }

            case DELETE_ITEM:
            console.log()
            return {
                list:[...state.list.slice(0, action.payload),
                      ...state.list.slice(action.payload + 1)]
            }

            case CURRENT_PRODUCT:
            return {
                ...state,
                currentProduct: payload
            }

            case INCREASE_AMOUNT:
    
            return {
                
                ...state,
                
            }
            
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

this is the file with the store config details:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist'
import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk'
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage'
import rootReducer from './rootReducers'

const persistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    storage,
}

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer)

let store = createStore(persistedReducer, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk))
let persistor = persistStore(store)

export { store, persistor }
```

and this is what i get when i console.log the state:
[console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wW2w1.png)

that result is from an older version

Answer (score 0):

you encountered that issue because you had applied persistence before you settled on how your Product reducer initial state should look like. to solve this you need to either temporarily include your reducer into the persistConfig blacklist or setting the stateReconciler to autoMerge.